# How does Mobile First Server communicate with Operational Analytics?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I'm preparing for MFP7 deployment. I would like to deploy MFP server into DMZ zone and Operational Analytics into corporate LAN which is separated by DataPower.

I'm looking for info on format of the data that is forwarded to Operational Analytics by MFP server. Is it JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1):

The data send from the client application to the Operational Analytics server is sent in JSON format.